# Identical particle exchange as a Yang-Mills theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, yang-mills, identical-particles

I am trying to find a quantum field theory (a Yang-Mills theory) for the identical particles exchange interaction. For a system of $N$ identical particles one has the state $|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\rangle$ that is invariant under permutations of states. The permutation operator $P$ is a discrete, not a continuous symmetry group. But is there a way turning the permutation operator $P$ into a continuous operator?

In a quantum field theory I have continuum states, i.e. the $\psi(x)$ (for fermions) function. Due to this fact I cannot define a proper permutation operator. However if I compute the $N$-point function (with $M$ ingoing and $N-M$ outgoing states)

$$\langle\psi_1 \psi_2 \ldots \psi^\dagger_{N-1}\psi^\dagger_N\rangle:=\int ~\mathrm d[\psi]\int ~\mathrm d[\psi^\dagger]e^{iS}(\psi_1 \psi_2 ... \psi^\dagger_{N-1}\psi^\dagger_N)$$

I could impose permutation symmetry in the functions $\psi_1,...\psi^\dagger_N$. If $N \mapsto \infty$ then I can define a function $P(x)$ (a local symmetry group) that fixes permuation symmetry on every point of spacetime.

How I can define a generalized permutation operator in continuum field?

Edit: I am trying to assume some additional symmetries in the quantum field vacuum, i.e. two fields of equal wave structure but on different spacetime points.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question is asking for. What is "a quantum field theory for the identical particles exchange interaction"? The very essence of QFT is that *fields*, not a fixed number of particles are the fundamental dynamical objects, and how is "exchange of identical particles" an *interaction*? The quantum field $\psi(x)$ isn't a "continuum state", it's an *operator*. Please make it more clear what you are trying to do and take care to use established terminology properly.

Comment: I think this question could potentially be interesting, but I can't understand what you're trying to ask, right now. I hope you can edit it (again) to make it more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Permutations in infinite dimensions are diffeomorphisms (assuming that you are considering only smooth configurations). An invariant theory under permutations, thus goes to a diffeomorphism invariant theory in the infinite dimension limit (such as gravity). If you want to include fermions, then the appropriate limit would be a diffeomorphism invariant theory over supermanifolds.